# How to save local values from inside onMounted hook - Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

how do I save assigned values from inside onMounted hook in Vue 3? My intention of saving the `width` and `height` values is so that can use to manipulate the values inside a `custom-directive` outside of the `setup` function later on.

I realised that it is only possible manipulating inside the `onMounted` and using `watch` see if there is a change to the value. But even so, after assigning the values, it is still `undefined`.

**Is using Vuex the way to go for my current solution?**

Because I can only access DOM properties inside `onMounted` hook and not anywhere else.

```
<template>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div class="border">
          <img
            id="image"
            ref="image"
            src="@/assets/1.jpg"
            class="image"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent, onMounted, watch } from "vue";

const widthVal = ref<number>()
const heightVal = ref<number>()

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const image = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

    onMounted(() => {
      if (image.value) {
        widthVal.value = image.value.offsetWidth;
        heightVal.value = image.value.offsetHeight;

        console.log('width: ', widthVal.value)
        console.log('height: ', heightVal.value)
      }
    })

    watch([widthVal, heightVal], (newVal, oldVal) => {
      widthVal.value = newVal[0];
      heightVal.value = newVal[1];

      console.log(widthVal.value)
      console.log(heightVal.value)
    })  

    // becomes undedefined 
    console.log('width: ', widthVal.value)

    return { image }
  }
});
</script>

<style>
p {
  color: yellow;
}
.outer {
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  background: rgb(98, 98, 98);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 950px;
  height: 650px;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Trebuchet Ms", helvetica, sans-serif;
}
img {
  width: 950px;
  height: 650px;

  /* remove margins */
  margin-left: -18px;
  margin-top: -18px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "still `undefined`"? The console log inside `onMounted` returns defined values?

Comment: When I try to access `widthVal` and `heightVal` outside of the `onMounted`, it will be `undefined` not inside `onMounted`. Just to be clear, I want to capture the `image.value.offsetWidth` and be able to access outside `onMounted`.

Comment: Where are you trying to access those values? I'm seeing that the only access is just a lone console.log inside the body of the component, in no particular place. Can you point me to where you're then trying to use `widthVal` and `heightVal`?

Comment: In line `31` and `32`, I am trying to store it globally into 'widthVal' and 'heightVal' inside `onMounted`. Hence, when I tried to access the global 'heightVal' outside `onMounted` it becomes `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, but where do you really access it? In the console.log outside of the lifecycle hooks? Do you use it in the template or inside any fn? It might be that the problem is Vue's reactivity system. Have you tried looking at this with the Vue debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect `widthVal` inside setup() and not inside the `watch` or `onMounted` function it gets called BEFORE the values are assigned cause assignments inside setup happen even before the `beforeCreate` hook.
See: [lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram)

EDIT:

If you really want to use `widthVal`/`heightVal` inside `setup` I'd recommend using it within a function (or a watcher, whatever you need) and calling that inside `onMounted` after you initialized `widthVal`/`heightVal`. E.g.:

```
const doSomethingElse = () => {
  // Use widthVal and heightVal here...    
}

onMounted(() => {
  widthVal.value = newVal[0];
  heightVal.value = newVal[1];

  doSomethingElse();
})  
...
```

Comment: That is much clearer now why `widthVal` is undefined. Then is there anyway for me store the values then? So I can update the value the value inside the setup() after `onMounted` is fired?

Comment: @liner183 I edited the answer. If it fits your needs just accept it. :)